# How to select paired list from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list.

```
{{1, 2, 3, 6, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 8, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 8,8}, {1, 2, 
7, 14, 10}}
```

Now I want to get those `#1[[-1]]==#2[[-1]] && #1[[-2]]==#2[[-2]]`

I will get

> { {{1, 2, 3, 6, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 6}} , {{1, 2, 5, 8, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 8,8}} }

`Subsets` can do it. But since my data is huge, my memory isn't big enough to hold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
Select[GatherBy[l, #[[{-2, -1}]] &], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 6, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 6}}, {{1, 2, 5, 8, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 8, 
>      8}}}